# Perl Looping Problems after Sub?

Tags: perl

I'm writing a program in Perl. I call a sub in a loop. After the sub is called the program stops looping over the remaining values in @list. Any ideas?

```
for($i = 0; $i <@list; i++){
    if($value{attrs[$i]} ne $otherValue{otherAttrs[$i]}){
         $convert = valueConvert(otherValue{otherAttrs[$i]}; 
         $value{attrs[$i]} = $convert; 
     }
 }
```

This is the sub

```
sub valueConvert{
    ($mValue) = @_;
    ....
    return $mValue
}
```

The value converts correctly in the sub and is returned to the main loop and is correctly assigned. So I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: Include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  This very likely could be the source of your issues, but you do not provide enough information to conclusively diagnose.

Comment: You should also add some print statements to debug the problem.  Print the size of @list, then each time through the loop  try printing `$i`.  That will tell you for sure if it is getting through every iteration.  My guess is that it is going through every iteration but your `if()` statement is not returning "true" every time so it appears that it is skipping things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show your actual code, since what you do show has errors and won't run.

Presumably valueConvert (or something it calls) is changing your $i or @list; I suspect that you are using global variables instead of lexically scoped variables.  If the problem is $i, not @list, you can simply do:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <@list; $i++){
```

to fix it.

Comment: That's what it was. Thank you

Comment: now go and add 'use strict; use warnings;' and make *all* of your variables lexicals :)